# How two compare two word documents if the original document is already open in desktop word using Microsoft.office.Interop.Word.Document?

Tags: asp.net-core, sharepoint, ms-word, compare, office-interop

Below is my C# dotnet core code that I am using but it doesn't work as I am opening doc1 and then comparing. Is there any way I can compare two word documents without opening the original document in my code because my original document is already opened in desktop word? I tried to use `wordApp.ActiveDocument` to get the currently opened document but it gives error that no document is opened although I have my word document opened locally?

```
Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();

wordApp.Visible = false;
object wordTrue = (object)true;
object wordFalse = (object)false;
object fileToOpen = @original;
object missing = Type.Missing;
Word.Document doc1 = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref fileToOpen,
       ref missing, ref wordFalse, ref wordFalse, ref missing,
       ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
       ref missing, ref missing, ref wordTrue, ref missing,
       ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

object fileToOpen1 = @revised;
Word.Document doc2 = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref fileToOpen1,
       ref missing, ref wordFalse, ref wordFalse, ref missing,
       ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
       ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

Word.Document doc = wordApp.CompareDocuments(doc1, doc2, Word.WdCompareDestination.wdCompareDestinationNew,
                    Word.WdGranularity.wdGranularityWordLevel,
                    true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, "", true);

doc1.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
doc2.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

// Hides both original and revised documents
wordApp.ActiveWindow.ShowSourceDocuments = WdShowSourceDocuments.wdShowSourceDocumentsNone;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running both frontend and backend locally which was creating this issue, I resolved this by deploying backend server on a different machine and then running compare and it worked like a charm. Hope my answer helps someone someday.